# Как включать музыку когда заходишь на сайт?

Tags: python, html, django

есть сайт https://marlin-dev.ru/
когда заходишь музыка то включается то нет. Чтобы точно заработал надо нажать на кнопку ГЛАВНАЯ.

сайт на пайтон+джанго
в хтмл прописан этот код(когда заходишь нас сайт через код элемента тоже показывает что есть)

```html
<audio autoplay="autoplay"  loop="loop" preload="preload" >
            <source src="{% static 'audi/fon.mp3' %}" />     
</audio>
```

Comment: Автоматическое включение звука запрещено во всех браузерах

Comment: хм... а как тут реализовано? 
https://niksdev.ru/ у меня сразу включается

Comment: Никак, браузер сразу автоматически заблокировал звук https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xaf7.png

Comment: странно у меня на яндекс сразу воспроизводиться